# How Can I Animate Changing the Size of a VideoView?

Tags: android, animation, transition, android-videoview

I have a VideoView that I want to change the size of dynamically in my app. By extending the VideoView class, I have successfully gotten both the video and videoView to change size correctly. However, I'd like to be able to transition between the two sizes more gradually. How can I do that? I've tried a scaling animation, but while that changes the VideoView layout's size, the video itself does not scale. Thoughts?

Here is my video class:

```
public class MyVideoView extends VideoView {

    private int mForceHeight,mForceWidth;
    private int mOrigWidth, mOrigHeight, mMinWidth, mMinHeight;


    public MyVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /* Will cause inflator errors if not present */
    public MyVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setDimensions(int w, int h) {
        this.mForceHeight = h;
        this.mForceWidth = w;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        if (mForceHeight != 0)
            setMeasuredDimension(mForceWidth, mForceHeight);
        else
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }


    public void setOrigDimens(int width, int height) {
        mOrigWidth = width;
        mOrigHeight = height;

        mMinWidth = width/4;    // My own decision for the small size
        mMinHeight = height/4;
    }


    public void setSmallView() {
        setNewViewSize(mMinWidth, mMinHeight);
    }


    public void setNormalView() {
        setNewViewSize(mOrigWidth, mOrigHeight);
    }


    /* RESIZES THE VIEW */
    public void setNewViewSize(int width, int height) {
        mForceWidth = width;
        mForceHeight = height;
        setDimensions(width, height);
        getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
    }
}
```

Here is the scaling code I tried:

```
Animation scaling = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f, 0.2f);
scaling.setDuration(2000);
startAnimation(scaling);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is to simply use a **TextureView** instead of a SurfaceView (a VideoView inherits from a SurfaceView by default). To do this, use code as follows:

Define your TextureView in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/videoTexture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent />
```

In your `MainActivity.java`, declare the following variables:

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private TextureView mVideoTextureView;
private float mDisplayWidth;
private float mDisplayHeight;
```

Then in your `onCreate()` method, initialize them as follows:

```
mVideoTextureView =(TextureView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.videoTexture);
mVideoTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
loadNewMovie();
```

To load a movie into the MediaPlayer, use the following code:

```
private void loadNewMovie() {

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(ID_OF_YOUR_MOVIE);

    try {

        // Set source

        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();

        /*
        // Gets the Height/Width of the video but does NOT include space
        // taken up by black bars if the dimensions don't exactly fit the screen.

        MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        String height = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        String width = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
        mVideoHeight = Float.parseFloat(height);
        mVideoWidth = Float.parseFloat(width);
        */

        // Gets the size of the display in pixels (used for scaling)

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        mDisplayWidth = size.x;
        mDisplayHeight = size.y;

        // Play movie

        if (currState == State.PLAYING)
            mMediaPlayer.start();

        afd.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "loadNewMovie: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(DEFAULT_VIDEO_INIT_POSITION);
}
```

Finally, your video can be adjusted instantaneously using the following code:

```
private void updateTextureViewSize(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth,viewHeight);

    // ANY OTHER RULES...EXAMPLE:
    // params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    mVideoTextureView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Or you can animate the change like this:

```
private void animateTextureViewScaling(final float startScaleX, final float startScaleY, 
                                       final float endScaleX, final float endScaleY, 
                                       int duration) {

    // Note: Can't just use .scaleX and .scaleY directly because it will only scale 
    // the video, not it's holder

    mVideoTextureView.animate().setDuration(duration)
        .setUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            float value, scalingX, scalingY;
            float changeXScale = startScaleX - endScaleX;
            float changeYScale = startScaleY - endScaleY;

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

                scalingX = (float) (startScaleX - changeXScale*value);
                scalingY = (float) (startScaleX - changeYScale*value);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) (mDisplayWidth*scalingX), (int) (mDisplayHeight*scalingY));

                // ANY OTHER RULES...EXAMPLE:
                // params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

                mVideoTextureView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

        }).start();
}
```

In the above code, I use `mDisplayWidth` (set in `loadNewVideo()`) as my video's original size. You can use whatever you want.

The **benefits** of this are that a TextureView can be animated, transformed, and scaled (a SurfaceView can't).

The **cons** are that a TextureView can only be used in a hardware accelerated window and will use much more memory (about 30%) more than a SurfaceView. It may also experience a 1 to 3 frame latency.

Comment: You are missing an essential part in this code... (I think). You should also set the MediaPlayer to use the TextureView. Probably in the onSurfaceTextureAvailable method from the SurfaceTextureListener..

Answer (score 2):

One solution I found is to use a ValueAnimator to change the ratio the size should be, and then use an update listener to force the video to actually change size. However, it's extremely jittery:

```
ValueAnimator scaleDown = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0.25f);
    scaleDown.setDuration(1000);

    scaleDown.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            setNewViewSize(mOrigWidth*value, mOrigHeight*value);
        }
    });

    scaleDown.start();
```